# How to get number of session in laravel project?

Tags: laravel, session, eloquent, session-state

I have a basic laravel project which have login, logout and some others basic public pages.

I would like to count all session for the current time(now time). Any session that should be count login user or visit any public pages.

From this project, I would like to know how many session is running?

Comment: There's no 100% reliable way to do this. You may be able to hack your way around it when using the database as a session store but if for example you're using cookie sessions then there's no server-side storage of any session information so in this case it would be impossible.

Comment: You could use google analytics. There is even a server side implementation that you could use incase some of the users of your site have disabled javascript.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question is, you want a feature in your application where you can count number of user that are logged in to the application.

If that's the case then as stated above you can hack a way around by adding a bool column in users table or whatever table you are using to store users, and whenever any user logs in, you change that column value to 1 and when the user logs out you change the column value to 0.

This way you can count the users by using that column where the column value is true or 1.

Hope this solves your problem.